# Java memory reference issue

Tags: java

Why does the below mentioned code prints 4,3,2,1,0  and why not 4,4,4,4,4. Since the reference sb is same  so why not it pointing towards the last updated value and why not it updating all the values as 4

```
package iteration;

import java.util.Stack;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack stack = new Stack();
        StringBuilder sb;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(i);
            stack.add(sb);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `pop` removes the last item. Use [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#peek--) instead. Also I don't understand why do you have a `StringBuilder` there..

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I think you've misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed. After reading your answer I realized that. It was my instinct when I saw "4,3,2,1", "4,4,4,4" and "Stack" in the same sentence :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Since the reference sb is same

It's not. You're using the `sb` *variable* each time, but each time you call `stack.add(sb)` it's adding "the current value of `sb`" which is different on each iteration due to this line:

```
sb = new StringBuilder();
```

It's very important to understand the difference between "a variable" and "the value that a variable currently holds".

When you execute `stack.add(sb);`, that evaluates the current value of `sb` (which will be a reference to a `StringBuilder` instance) and then passes that reference to `Stack.add`. When you later change the value of `sb`, that *doesn't* change the value on the stack.

Now, compare that with this code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBulder();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    sb.append(i);
    stack.add(sb);
}
```

At that point, you'd have 5 references to the same `StringBuilder` object on the stack, and you'd print out "01234" five times. This time you're modifying the content of the existing object, rather than changing `sb`'s value.

Answer (score 0):

You need `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();` being placed **outside** `for` loop to reference to the same object.